# QT 5.3 release application

Tags: c++, qt, dll, release

Trying to release my application written with QT 5.3. Did my homework on this question, I added the following .dll files to my working directory:

```
release:
icudt52.dll
icuin52.dll
icuuc52.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESV2.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5SerialPort.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
qtquik2plugin.dll
qtquik2plugind.dll
qwindows.dll
```

Error: could not find or the Qt platform windows, I did add the `qwindows.dll` from location: `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\platforms` also available from: `C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013\plugins\platforms`

> update after using windeployqt

Got an extra directory in my application folder called platforms, contains `qwinrt.dll`. When I copy paste `qwindows.dll` into this folder the application does not start, but no errors are given. `qwinrt.dll` is for Windows 8.1, I'm using 7.

Comment: use `windeployqt` feature of Qt

Comment: It has to be in YourApplicationFolder\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll

Comment: @vishal Thankyou, I tried it. Now I'm getting the same error but, it does say: Available platform plugins are winrt?

Comment: Don’t forget the msvc redistributables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qwindows.dll needs to be put into a subdirectory called /platforms of the directory where your exe is installed. It is not enough to put them both into the same directory.
I do not think, that your need qwinrt.dll.

You can check missing dlls with depends.exe (google for downloads).